# Max-height and margin-bottom work fine in Webkit, not in Firefox

Tags: html, css

My goal is to make the second div take as much space as it needs. If the browser window is to small the scrollbar should appear inside the div. Working fine in Webkit but not in Firefox.

I'm guessing that the problem have something with:

- max-height
- height: 100%
- max-height & margin.

If I give HTML and BODY ***height*** and/or ***max-height*** the max-height is working but the extra margin on the body is not working -- Not in Webkit or Firefox.

**You can find the code here:**
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/514866/uploaded/box-test.html

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chosen doctype of `<!HTML>` does not trigger standards mode, so your page is being displayed in quirks mode.

Try changing your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and then repeating your tests.

Comment: It's not even a doctype. It's... what is it? I don't know. It's anything *but* a doctype.

Comment: @BoltClock: I always wonder where people get stuff like this from. w3schools?

Answer (score 0):

use these one

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```